# Как убрать маску с номера телефона, на странице checkout

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Помогите убрать маску номера страны `(8)`, который автоматически подставляет WooCommerce в `input`, пользователю нужно ввести полный телефон. При этом, чтобы данные телефона приходили корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал изменять через `$("#billing_phone").mask("(999) 99?9-9999");`
Но ничего не помогает

Comment: Можно ссылку на сайт?

Answer (score 0):

Подбор маски ввода по телефонному номеру [Данный плагин для jQuery](https://habr.com/post/162537/) позволяет автоматически подбирать подходящую маску ввода на основе введённого начала телефонного номера